# Faster dot product of CSR matrix and ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to get a fast dot product function for multiplying a sparse matrix(3*3) and an nd array(1*3) in such a way that every row of matrix gets dot product with nd array to get a (3*1) array.

My current implementation is to get each row of the matrix and then do the dot product but for scaling up the matrix dimension, it gets too slow.

```
row = np.array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2])
col = np.array([0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2])
data = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
matrix =csr_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(3, 3))
secondArray=np.random.rand((1, 3))

for idx, x in enumerate(matrix):
    X_arr=X.getrow(idx).toarray()
    prod=np.dot(np.array(X_arr[0]), secondArray)
```

Comment: You've constructed the matrix and array, but don't show how you do the calc.  Don't just describe it, show it.  The demo matrix is quite dense, 6 out of possible 9 nonzeros.  Why are you using sparse in this case?

Comment: Hi, it is just an example, the real data I'm dealing with has dimensions in thousands and have many zeroes in the csr matrix, just for convenience I have made this example

Comment: Your for loop doesn't work.

Comment: Why don't you just do `matrix * secondArray.T`?  I.e. a matrix product of (3,3) with (3,1).  Or `matrix.A.dot(secondArray.T)`?

Comment: In the loop, why iterate on matrix, getting `x`, and then ignore that?  Isn't `x` the same as `matrix.getrow(idx)`?   In general iterating over a sparse matrix is a slow process, as is indexing specific rows or columns.